# JavaScript visit every node in graph

Tags: javascript, graph

I want to create a graph where every node is connected to its childs

```
function Node (value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.childs = [];
    this.mark = false;
}
```

This is my graph

```
var nodes = [new Node (0), new Node (1), new Node (2), new Node (3), new Node (4)];

nodes[0].childs.push (nodes[1]);
nodes[1].childs.push (nodes[0]);

nodes[1].childs.push (nodes[2]);
nodes[2].childs.push (nodes[1]);

nodes[1].childs.push (nodes[4]);
nodes[4].childs.push (nodes[1]);

nodes[2].childs.push (nodes[3]);
nodes[3].childs.push (nodes[2]);
```

Should look like this

[image: graph]

Now I want to visit every node

```
function visit (node) {
    node.mark = true;
    for (i=0; i<node.childs.length; i++)
        if (!node.childs[i].mark)
            visit (node.childs[i]);
}
```

But node 4 never gets visited what I don't unterstand.
See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jhdLhz44/

Would be nice if someone can help.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` has a global scope.

So the iterations over the children arrays are using the same `i` and interfering with each other.

Make it a local variable by adding `var`.

```
for (var i=0; i<node.childs.length; i++)
    if (!node.childs[i].mark)
        visit (node.childs[i]);
```

---

FYI, a prettier and less error-prone way is to use `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
node.childs.forEach(function(child) {
    if (!child.mark)
        visit (child);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think structuring your data as an object rather than an array with sub-arrays would simplify things.

If you structure your data like this:

```
var nodes = {
    "0": {
        mark: false,
        "1": {
            mark: false,
            "2": {
                "3": {
                    mark: false
                }
            },
            "4": {
                mark: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then more easily visit each node like this:

```
(function visit(obj) {
    obj.mark = true;
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            visit(obj[key]);
        }
    }
})(nodes);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhdLhz44/2/) example.

So what you really need to address, I think, is how your constructor works.  Good luck :)

Comment: This structure does not provide a graph, only a tree